# ASP.Net Core: Hundreds of Build Errors Suddenly

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

What might cause an ASP.Net Core web application to display hundreds of build errors suddenly without explanation? I started working on an app I had not worked on for awhile and when I clicked publish I got hundreds of build errors that never existed before.

Some were quite simple. Like this block of code used for a Blazor component (file extention .razor) that never had problems before. This block displays red squiggly lined underneath both instances of the string "crumbicon" I can think of no reason why there would be a problem with this:

```
@using PostAlmostAnything.Models
@crumbicon<a href="@GlobalStatic.SITEURL()">Home</a>

@code {
    string crumbicon = "<<";
}
```

The exact errors say that there is "ambiguity between filename.crumbicon and filename.crumbicon "the type [blazor file name] already contains a definition for crumbicon". This error has never been encountered before, but now exists on every .razor file that was designed this way.

The other error appear related to various assemblies or variables on pages. They typically say that something has already been defined someplace else, but if the code were the problem then it would have been an error long ago and not suddenly.

When I try to update Nuget packages they say the updates are not compatible with version 3.1 of .Net Core.

Comment: `What might cause an ASP.Net Core web application to display hundreds of build errors suddenly without explanation?` I suspect you broke something. Check in your source control tool - what did you change?

Comment: If you have lots of errors some might be very similar so copy and paste a few of them.

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to this sooner. I upgraded everything to .Net 5.0 and still the exact same error messages. On top of that when I click yes after being asked if I want to run the last successful build I get "HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure"

Comment: I am honestly thinking of just exporting my database to a CSV, importing it into MySql, and trying to convert the site to a Wordpress site. The only thing stopping me is the ASP.Net membership provider.

Comment: Here is an example that proved I didn't break the app. It is an error that comes with every page in the Identity area which were created by Microsoft and not me Severity 
Error CS0111 Type 'Areas_Identity_Pages_Account_RegisterConfirmation' already defines a member called 'ExecuteAsync' with the same parameter types

Comment: I also noticed that new folders are not being automatically included in the project. Plus, some error messages appear to be looking for deleted razor pages.

Comment: Somehow I got it all down to just one build error after updating to 5.0 and deleting the obj/bin folders but I still get this: microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui\5.0.8\build\..\staticwebassets\V4\css\site.css' has a conflicting web root path '/wwwroot/Identity/css/site.css' with the project file 'wwwroot\Identity\css\site.css'

Comment: Deleted the identity stuff from wwwroot changed the problem, but I had to change the file URLs in the validation scripts file to use scripts in the lib folder. Now my app will build and load with an error in my browser that says "A database operation failed while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version: jiggle it until it works.**

This happens a lot.  I think it's a conflict between an old assembly that didn't get cleared out of Intellisense and a new one or something like that.  You can try any / some of:

- clean and rebuild
- close all open files and re-open them
- just ignore the errors and run the app
- delete the bin folder from your project
- restart Visual Studio
- go get yourself a coffee and wait for Visual Studio to figure it out
  on its own

Comment: Ignoring the errors and running the app results in "HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure" will deleting the bin folder cause other problems?

Comment: Okay, that's different then.  Just a stab in the dark-- have you upgraded the .NET version of your project recently?

Comment: That error isn't just Intellisense-- something about .NET is not configured properly.

Comment: The error I wrote this post about it basically resolved, but now I found out that 5.0 broke my queries. I posted a question on Github and all i get is a bunch of tech jibberish about concrete types, anonymous types, and nullable types.

Comment: So the project builds and runs, but the queries fail?  In that case, I recommend closing this question and forming a new one about that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to close Visual Studio and reopen. That always works for me to get the libraries back

Comment: That is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: this is better off as a comment, not an answer

Comment: The OP had "hundreds of build errors suddently" and @xstaticvoidx explained hw to solve that problem.  Does everything need to come in the form of a doctoral dissertation?

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on?"  (in Irish accent)  ^^

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio is never stable nowadays.
Try cleaning and rebuilding or cleaning obj and bin directories. this may help too

Answer (score 0):

Of course, try the other suggestions mentioned in the other great answers here.

Another option is to comment out the offending lines that are giving you problems, then rebuild. Keep commenting/building until it works.  Once it builds and starts again, uncomment sections one at a time until you are back up and running.

As an extra bonus you may find an errant "}" or missing tag that helped cause the issue in the first place.